# RavenDB ArgumentOutOfRangeException Index Creation - Version 4.2.102

Tags: exception, ravendb

I just updated my project dependencies, and one of them was a RavenDB upgrade. From 4.2.101 -> 4.2.102. After this, I am getting exceptions thrown for argument out of range. Nothing has changed to my codebase, and rolling back to version 4.2.101 fixes this issue. I've tried to find some sort of explanation as to why this is happening, but I can't find anything. I hope someone here can shed some light on this issue.

Exception happens when an index is being executed:

```
Exception thrown: 'Raven.Client.Exceptions.RavenException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An exception of type 'Raven.Client.Exceptions.RavenException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: column
Actual value was -17.
   at Esprima.Position..ctor(Int32 line, Int32 column)
   at Esprima.ErrorHandler.CreateError(Int32 index, Int32 line, Int32 col, String description)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.UnexpectedTokenError(Token token, String message)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ThrowUnexpectedToken(Token token, String message)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.IsolateCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseNewExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.InheritCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.InheritCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseUpdateExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseUnaryExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.InheritCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseExponentiationExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.InheritCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseBinaryExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.InheritCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseConditionalExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseAssignmentExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.IsolateCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseAssignmentExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.IsolateCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseArguments()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.InheritCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseUpdateExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseUnaryExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.InheritCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseExponentiationExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.InheritCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseBinaryExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.InheritCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseConditionalExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseAssignmentExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.IsolateCoverGrammar[T](Func`1 parseFunction)
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseExpression()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseLabelledStatement()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseStatement()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseStatementListItem()
   at Esprima.JavaScriptParser.ParseProgram(Boolean strict)
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.Static.JavaScriptIndex.ExecuteCodeAndCollectReferencedCollections(String code) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42034\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\Static\JavaScriptIndex.cs:line 196
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.Static.JavaScriptIndex.InitializeEngine(IndexDefinition definition) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42034\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\Static\JavaScriptIndex.cs:line 221
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.Static.JavaScriptIndex..ctor(IndexDefinition definition, RavenConfiguration configuration) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42034\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\Static\JavaScriptIndex.cs:line 54
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.Static.IndexCompilationCache.GenerateIndex(IndexDefinition definition, RavenConfiguration configuration, IndexType type) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42034\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\Static\IndexCompilationCache.cs:line 75
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.Static.IndexCompilationCache.GetIndexInstance(IndexDefinition definition, RavenConfiguration configuration) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42034\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\Static\IndexCompilationCache.cs:line 41
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.IndexStore.ValidateStaticIndex(IndexDefinition definition) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42034\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\IndexStore.cs:line 689
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Indexes.IndexStore.CreateIndex(IndexDefinition definition, String raftRequestId, String source) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42034\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Indexes\IndexStore.cs:line 560
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Handlers.Admin.AdminIndexHandler.PutInternal(Boolean validatedAsAdmin) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42034\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Handlers\Admin\AdminIndexHandler.cs:line 74
   at Raven.Server.Documents.Handlers.Admin.AdminIndexHandler.PutJavaScript() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42034\src\Raven.Server\Documents\Handlers\Admin\AdminIndexHandler.cs:line 30
   at Raven.Server.Routing.RequestRouter.HandlePath(RequestHandlerContext reqCtx) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42034\src\Raven.Server\Routing\RequestRouter.cs:line 184
   at Raven.Server.RavenServerStartup.RequestHandler(HttpContext context) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42034\src\Raven.Server\RavenServerStartup.cs:line 173
```

Index:

```
    public class SystemMetrics_ByDate : AbstractIndexCreationTask<SystemMetrics>
    {
        public SystemMetrics_ByDate()
        {
            Map = metrics => from metric in metrics
                             orderby metric.Created descending
                             select new 
                             {
                                  metric.Created
                             };
        }
    }
```

SystemMetrics:

```
    public class SystemMetrics
    {
        public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        public CpuMetrics? Cpu { get; set; }
        public MetricData? Memory { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, MetricData>? Disks { get; set; }
    }
```

The only idea i have, is that ravendb changed something regarding nullables. Reading here: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/start/whats-new?page=1#42038 i found this: "[Indexing] JavaScript indexes should not index implicit null values" which i believe is the culprit.

Anyone have an idea what they mean by this? As my index is on the Created property, which has a default value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a bug

https://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-14903

Comment: Thank you! I was unable to access that issue tracker the other day.